# Tokenize a string with std::views

Tags: c++20, string-view

I want to iterate over token which I have extracted from the std::wcin stream, using the functions and classes of the C++ std library. I tried this:

```
    auto input = std::views::istream<wchar_t>(std::wcin);
    auto tokens = input | std::views::lazy_split(L' ');

    for (auto const& token : tokens)
    {
      std::wstring s1(token); // doesn't compile
      std::wstring s;
      s = token; // doesn't compile
      s = std::wstring(token); // doesn't compile
      s = std::wstring{token.begin(), token.end()}; // doesn't compile
      s = std::wstring(token.begin(), token.end()); // doesn't compile
      s = std::wstring(token.cbegin(), token.cend()); // doesn't compile
      // action goes here - requires the token to be a string
      do_something_with_the_token_string(s);
    }
```

Unfortunately, I didn't find a way to convert `token` into a `wstring`. How is it done? According to the error messages, the type of `token` is `std::ranges::lazy_split_view<std::ranges::basic_istream_view<wchar_t,_Elem,_Traits>,std::ranges::single_view<wchar_t>>::_Outer_iter<false>::value_type`.

Using Visual Studio 17.9.1 with /std:c++20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allowed to use `/std:c++latest` instead of `/std:c++20` you can use the C++23 feature [`std::ranges::to`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/to):

```cpp
auto input = std::views::istream<wchar_t>(std::wcin >> std::noskipws);
auto tokens = input | std::views::lazy_split(L' ');

for (auto const token : tokens) {
    auto s1 = std::ranges::to<std::wstring>(token);
    // ...
}
```

Note: I assume that you've set `std::noskipws` in `std::wcin` in code that you've not shown, but I included that above just in case you haven't. Without it, there will be no spaces in the view to make the split on.

---

In C++20 I think you will have to settle for copying:

```cpp
for (auto const& token : tokens) {
    std::wstring s1;
    std::ranges::copy(token, std::back_inserter(s1));
    // ...
}
```